# How to create an abbreviation that matches a regular expression

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, abbreviations

I'd like to create an abbreviation that will change the following (in a markdown file):

```
- list item 1
```

into this:

```
-   list item 1
```

Whenever I type `- f` it should be expanded to `-   f` (from 1 space to 3 spaces between the dash and the next non-white char).

This seems like an ideal situation to use abbreviations in, but `help abbreviations` doesn't mention regex.

If abbreviations don't accept regular expressions, could someone suggest an alternative approach? Ideally without needing a plugin.

Comment: You can't define an abbreviation with a regex. I think you have several options: 1) Use a loop to define as many abbreviations as there are combinations of  `-   [symbol]` which is not ideal because you can miss possibilities 2) Create a mapping which will run `:s/- \(\w\)/-   \1/` this way you can trigger the substitution easily 3) Use a snippet engine plugin, you could define `- L` as a snippet trigger which would allow you to replace `L` with your actual item

Comment: Note you cannot define abbreviations with spaces, according to `:help abbreviations`

Comment: Also, welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, especially @statox.

I think the easiest way to do this is to use [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) and define an automatic snippet. It's somewhat frustrating how limited vim abbreviations are, but UltiSnips really seems like a well designed and reliable plugin.

I made the following snippet in `UltiSnips/markdown.snippets` - replace the underscores with spaces.

```
snippet "^- " "markdown unordered list" rbA
-___
endsnippet

snippet "^[0-9]. " "markdown ordered list" rbA
1.__
endsnippet
```